# Reference seperate project assembly in Team Services build

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, tfsbuild, msbuild-task

I have a shared resources project that I'd like to reference as part of my Team Services build, is there an existing task that can obtain these assemblies so that they are available to the MSBuild task?

I know I can have a libraries folder within a project to hold these references but I'd rather build from a central source and not have the noise of these additional folders in my projects.

Comment: Obtain them from where? The standard approach for this is nuget package management.

Comment: From a separate Team Services project that I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put binary references in source control. Turn your binary references into NuGet packages and allow your build process to restore the appropriate version of your NuGet package as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a VS Team Services [extension for Package Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed) that will likely help you accomplish this.  You can publish the outputs of your shared project as a private NuGet feed and then consume the feed in your other projects.

These references may also help:

- Conceptual - https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/package/what-is-packaging
- Overview - https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/package/overview